# Apportable won't install

Tags: ios, terminal, installation, apportable

I am trying to install the Apportable SDK. I copied the command from the "my accounts" page into terminal but instead of downloading this is what happens:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
Abdullah-Shafiques-Mac:~ Abd$
```

My internet connection works. I do not have any firewalls or proxy on.

Comment: It does not progress over time? Does your internet connection work? If so, I would check if a firewall, router or proxy is blocking access to certain services. Not sure what service, domain name / IP and port is used by that command, so if in doubt temporarily disable all proxy and firewall settings or ask your system admin.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D My internet connection does work. I do not have any firewalls or proxy on so I don't think that is the problem. Any chance the link Apportable gave me is dead?

Comment: Can you test it on another machine, preferably with a different internet access provider? Also try deleting ~/.apportable to reset apportable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the script, it should be fixed later today. Watch this thread for more info: http://forum.apportable.com/t/cannot-download-sdk/193